# elementary set theory help

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $g$ be a function on a subset of $A\times N$ into $A, a\in A$. Then $\exists!$ sequence $f$ of elements of $A$ such that (a) $f_0=a$. (b) $f_{n+1} =g(f_n,n), \forall n\in N$ such that $(n+1) \in D_f$. (c) $f$ is either an infinite sequence or $f$ is a finite sequence of length $k+1$ and $g(f_k,k)$ is undefined.

Is my proof correct:
Let $A'= A\cup$ {$a'$} where $a'\not\in A$.  Define $g': A'\times N\to A'$ by

$$
g'(x,n) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&g(x,n) &&, (x,n)\in D_g\\
&a' &&,otherwise
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

By Recursion theorem, $\exists!f':N\to A'$ where $f'(0)=a$ and 
$$
f'_{n+1} = g'(f'_n,n)= \left\{\begin{aligned}
&g(f'_n,n) &&, (f'_n,n)\in D_g\\
&a' &&,otherwise
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

If $a'\not\in R_{f'}$, let $f'=f$. Then $(a),(b),(c)$ are satisfied.

If $a'\in R_{f'}$, let $m=k+1\in N$ be the minimum element such that $f'_{k+1}=a'$ (since $f'_0=a,  m\geq 1)$ 
Let $ f = \left\{{(0,f'_0),...,(k, f'_{k})}\right\}$. Then, $f$ is a function with $D_ f = k+1$ and $f$ satisfies $(a),(b)$. Suppose $g(f_{k},k)$ is defined, then $g(f_{k},k)=g'(f_k,k)=g'(f'_k,k)= f'_{k+1} = a'$, contrary to definition of $g$.

Comment: After a quick read, your reasoning seems to be valid. However, it stands out to me that you have not proven the uniqueness of $f$.